Regularization model in R
I've built a glmnet model with following parameters:
model_1 <- cv.glmnet(
  X_factors %>% as.matrix(),
  data_for_modeling$salary %>% log(),
  family = "gaussian", 
  alpha = 0,
  lower.limits = 0
)

I need to get all not zero coefficients, but finally, model always make some coefficients equal to zero.
I tried to use penalty.factor and offset, but, honestly, I didn't totally understand how offset parameter works.
All in all, in spite of these attempts, some coefficients were zero.
How can I get all not zero coefficients?
